# Is there a way to integrate macros with google forms?

Tags: google-forms

I have a basic google form with a short answer input. I'd like to split the input of the form by commas so text input like

> aaa, bbb, ccc

would appear in the spreadsheet as

[image]

I've tried adding the following macro to column C

```
=ArrayFormula(split(B1:B500, ","))
```

but the problem is that new form submissions will just create a new row without the macro applied to columns C, D, E, etc. Is there a way to ensure the macro gets applied to new rows created from users submitting the google form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the solution was to change the macro formula from

```
=ArrayFormula(split(B1:B500, ","))
```

to

```
=ArrayFormula(split(B1, ","))
```

then manually drag the formula down as many rows as needed. Not really sure why this was the case.